# Does StatsModels' power.tt_ind_solve_power assume a single standard deviation despite two different means?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, t-test, statistical-power

Does StatsModels' power.tt_ind_solve_power ([link](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.power.tt_ind_solve_power.html)) assume a single standard deviation despite two different means? I think so. Why is this a reasonable assumption?

I come from a primarily Bayesian background, so if I wanted to pool variances, I'd probably draw $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ from the same prior distribution.

I don't follow the logic that the means would be the different but the variances would be the same.

There is a ratio parameter (what % is population 1?) Perhaps this is used to decouple the variances?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this function use's Cohen's d for the effect size which relies on a pooled standard deviation. Obviously, for certain distributions such as a binomial distribution where the variance is given by the mean, this doesn't make a lot of sense, but for a t-test, it's not unlike the pooled variance version of the t-test. The ratio parameter is not very directly related to this but rather to the fact that for optimal power, in most cases, both sample should be of equal size.

Answer (score 0):

In many statistical software programs, 'power and sample size' procedures for a two-sample t test assume equal variances and sample sizes. There is a straightforward computation in such cases, which uses a noncentral t distribution.

For a Welch t test, the degrees of freedom $\nu$ depends on sample sizes and *sample* variances, so the approximate power for given sample size(s) is often found by simulation.

For example, the power of a *Welch* 2-sample test at the 5% level
for $\mu_1 = 50, \mu_2 = 55,$ $\sigma_1 = 5, \sigma_2=7,$ $n_1 = 30, n_2 = 25$ can be simulated
in R as about 83%.

```
set.seed(2022)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(30,50,5),
                      rnorm(25,55,7))$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.8313
```

For a *pooled* test, a recent release of Minitab
gives the following exact results:

```
Power and Sample Size 

2-Sample t Test

Testing mean 1 = mean 2 (versus ≠)
Calculating power for mean 1 = mean 2 + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 6

            Sample
Difference    Size     Power
         5      25  0.823010
         5      30  0.887557
The sample size is for each group.
```

[image]